# How to position variable width and height boxes floating left as one-vertically in each line?

Tags: positioning, css-float, css

I have lot of boxes (display: inline-block + float: left) with variety of width and height like this:

```
AA BB CC DDD EE FF GG
   BB    DDD    FF
         DDD
```

And i don't know how to do, that when box have to be wrapped, it will be aligned in next "line" like that:

```
AA BB CC DDD EE FF GG
   BB    DDD    FF
         DDD
EE
```

Not as natural float: left:

```
AA BB CC DDD EE FF GG
   BB    DDD    FF EE
         DDD
```

Real example (**current state**):

[image: BAD positioning]

**Expected result** wich i want to achieve:

[image]

**jsFiddle demo:** [here](http://jsfiddle.net/tdSnH/)

Comment: Can you create a [jsFiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/) of what you have so far?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your demo, you have both `float: left` and `display: inline-block`. `float: left` forces `display: block`, so `display: inline-block` was doing nothing whatsoever.

You can achieve your desired result with `display: inline-block; vertical-align: top`.

**See:** http://jsfiddle.net/tdSnH/1/

Comment: Thanks a lot, that is exactly what I want... It was mind breaker for me, I was so close to write some complicated JS-watcher-and-div-clear-both-inserter

Answer (score 0):

```
<style>
    #container{
       min-width:100px;
       max-width:1024px;/*see your boxes' container width*/
    }
   #container .item{
      float:left;
      min-width:10px;/*some value*/
      max-width:256px; /* #container with / item.length */
    }
</style>
<div id="container">
    <div class="item">a</div>
    <div class="item">bbbbb</div>
    <div class="item">ccc</div>
    <div class="item">d</div>
</div>
```